# Using Highlight Module with Default Search Module

Tags: views, theming

I'm trying to use this [highlight module](https://www.drupal.org/project/highlight) to highlight search terms on my site but can't seem to get it to work. I'm using Drupal 7, the basic search module that comes with Drupal, and Views to display the search interface (and results).

I *think* the main issue has to do with inputting a correct JavaScript syntax (regex) for local searches but the example given in the screenshot on the module page (linked above) only shows regex for apache solr and I'm wondering if anyone know what I should use for the default search, or if its even possible?

**Note: I've already changed the 'Highlight area' option on the highlight module configuration page to .search (which is the body class for my search view).**

Answer (score 0):

I think, looking at the examples, that something like this expression should work if you have clean URLs turned on and searches have URLs like http://example.com/search/node/keywords.

```
\/search\/node\/([^?#]+)
```

But I have never used this module and it looks a bit ropey. You can test your own regular expressions at https://regex101.com/ (use JavaScript mode). Contrary to the examples you should not need to include the domain of your site in the search patterns.